# Put cell on silent using background service

Tags: android, database, cursor

So I am comparing my current location with one I stored in my database.Everything is going fine but I am not able to make my cell on silent when I send location using emulator control.Logcat is saying that cursor is OutOfBounds

Here's my code

```
                            Cursor cur=null;
            cur=y.rawQuery("SELECT longitude FROM data",null);
            cur.moveToFirst();
            cr=y.rawQuery("SELECT latitude FROM data",null);
            cr.moveToFirst();
            while(!cr.isAfterLast()) {

                arlist.add(cr.getDouble(cr.getColumnIndex("latitude")));
                cr.moveToNext();
                }
            while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {

                arrylist.add(cr.getDouble(cr.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
                cur.moveToNext();
                }
            for(int i=0;i<arlist.size();i++){
                Location locB = new Location("point B");
                locB.setLatitude(arlist.get(i));
                locB.setLongitude(arrylist.get(i));
                float distance=loc.distanceTo(locB);
                if(distance<5){
                    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
                      .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                }
                else{
                    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
                      .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                }

            }
```

Here's my logcat

```
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 requested, with a size of 20
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getDouble(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:86)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.example.alert.service$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(service.java:90)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:170)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:186)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 09:45:16.528: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this loop, where you are looping against `cur` but trying to retrieve from `cr`:

```
while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
    arrylist.add(cr.getDouble(cr.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
    cur.moveToNext();
}
```

It should probably be:

```
while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
    arrylist.add(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("longitude")));
    cur.moveToNext();
}
```